# c code is running to slow from nested for loops

Tags: performance, loops, for-loop, nested

my c program is running to slow (right now it is around 40 seconds without parallelization).  I have tried using openmp which has brought the timing down significantly but I am looking to use simple and natural ways to make my code run faster other than using parallel for loops.  The basic structure of the code is that is takes some command line arguments as inputs and then saves those inputs as variables.  Then it recursively computes a variable called Rplus1 using the math.h library and the complex.h library.  The problem of the code and where it is taking most of it's time is at the bottom where there are nested for loops.  My goal is to get the whole code running in under 5 seconds but as of now it runs in about 40 seconds without using parallel for loops.  Please Help!

```
#include "time.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "complex.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "omp.h"
#define PI 3.14159265


int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
if(argc >= 8){

double start1 = omp_get_wtime();

// command line arguments are aligned in the following order: [theta] [number of layers in superlattice] [material_1] [lat const_1] [number of unit cells_1] [material_2] [lat const_2] [number of unit cells_2] .... [material_N] [lat const_N] [number of unit cells_N] [Log/Linear] [number of repeating superlattice layers] [yes/no]

int N;
sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&N); // Number of layers in superlattice specified by second input argument


if(strcmp(argv[argc-1],"yes") == 0) //If the substrate is included then add one more layer to the N variable
{
        N = N+1;
}

int total;
sscanf(argv[argc-2],"%d",&total); // Number of repeating superlattice layers specified by second to last argument

double layers[N][6], horizangle[1001], vertangle[1001]; 

double complex (*F_hkl)[1001][1001] = malloc(N*1001*1001*sizeof(complex double)), (*F_0)[1001][1001] = malloc(N*1001*1001*sizeof(complex double)), (*g)[1001][1001] = malloc(N*1001*1001*sizeof(complex double)), (*g_0)[1001][1001] = malloc(N*1001*1001*sizeof(complex double)),SF_table[10];// this array will hold the unit cell structure factors for all of the materials selected for each wavevector in the beam spectrum

double real, real2, lam, c_light = 299792458, h_pl = 4.135667516e-15,E = 10e3, r_0 = 2.818e-15, Lccd = 1.013;// just a few variables to hold values through calculations and constants, speed of light, plancks const, photon energy, and detector distance from sample

double angle;

double complex z;// just a variable to hold complex numbers throughout calculations

int i,j,m,n,t; // integers to index through arrays

lam = (h_pl*c_light)/E;

sscanf(argv[1],"%lf",&angle); //first argument is the angle of incidence, read it
angle = angle*(PI/180.0);
angle2 = -angle;


double (*table)[10] = malloc(10*9*sizeof(double)); // this array holds all the coefficients to calculate the atomic scattering factor below
double (*table2)[10] = malloc(10*2*sizeof(double));

FILE*datfile1 = fopen("/home/vhosts/xraydev.engr.wisc.edu/data/coef_table.bin","rb"); // read the binary file containg all the coefficients
fread(table,sizeof(double),90,datfile1);
fclose(datfile1);

FILE*datfile2 = fopen("/home/vhosts/xraydev.engr.wisc.edu/data/dispersioncs.bin","rb");
fread(table2,sizeof(double),20,datfile2);
fclose(datfile2);

// Calculate scattering factors for all elements
double a,b;
double k_z = (sin(angle)/lam)*1e-10; // incorporate angular dependence of SF but neglect 0.24 degree divergence because of approximation

for(i = 0;i<10;i++) // for each element...
{
    SF_table[i] = 0;
    for(j = 0;j<4;j++) // summation
    {
        a = table[2*j][i];
        b = table[2*j+1][i];
        SF_table[i] = SF_table[i] + a * exp(-b*k_z*k_z);
    }
    SF_table[i] = SF_table[i] + table[8][i] + table2[0][i] + table2[1][i]*I; 
}

free(table);



double mm = 4.0, (*phi)[1001][1001] = malloc(N*1001*1001*sizeof(double));

for(i = 1; i < N+1; i++) // for each layer of material...
{

    sscanf(argv[i*3+1],"%lf",&layers[i-1][1]);  // get out of plane lattice constant

    sscanf(argv[i*3+2],"%lf",&layers[i-1][2]);  // get the number of unit cells in the layer


    layers[i-1][1] = layers[i-1][1]*1e-10; // convert lat const input to meters



// Define reciprocal space positions at the incident angle h, k, l

    layers[i-1][3] = 0; // h
    layers[i-1][4] = 0; // k

    double l; // l calculated for each wavevector in the spectrum because l changes with angle of incidence



    for (m = 0; m < 1001; m++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n <1001; n++)
        {

        l = 4;

        phi[i-1][m][n] = 2*PI*layers[i-1][1]*sin(angle)/lam; // Caculate phi for each layer

        if(strcmp(argv[i*3],"GaAs") == 0)
        {
            F_hkl[i-1][m][n] = (2+2*cexp(I*PI*l))*(SF_table[2]+SF_table[3]*cexp(I*PI*l/2));
            F_0[i-1][m][n] = 0.5*8.0*(31 + table2[0][2] + table2[1][2]*I) + 0.5*8.0*(33 + table2[0][3] + table2[1][3]*I);
            g[i-1][m][n] = 2*r_0*F_hkl[i-1][m][n]/mm/layers[i-1][1]*cos(2*angle[m][n]);
            g_0[i-1][m][n] = 2*r_0*F_0[i-1][m][n]/mm/layers[i-1][1];
        }

        if(strcmp(argv[i*3],"AlGaAs") == 0)
        {
            F_hkl[i-1][m][n] = (2+2*cexp(I*PI*l))*((0.76*SF_table[2]+ 0.24*SF_table[4])+SF_table[3]*cexp(I*PI*l/2));
            F_0[i-1][m][n] = 0.24*4.0*(13 + table2[0][4] + table2[1][4]*I) + 0.76*4.0*(31 + table2[0][2] + table2[1][2]*I) + 4.0*(33 + table2[0][3] + table2[1][3]*I);
            g[i-1][m][n] = 2*r_0*F_hkl[i-1][m][n]/mm/layers[i-1][1]*cos(2*angle[m][n]);
            g_0[i-1][m][n] = 2*r_0*F_0[i-1][m][n]/mm/layers[i-1][1];
        }
      }
    }
}


   double complex (*Rplus1)[1001] = malloc(1001*1001*sizeof(double complex));

    for (m = 0; m < 1001; m++)
    {
            for (n = 0; n <1001; n++)
            {

            Rplus1[m][n] = 0.0;
            }
    }


double stop1 = omp_get_wtime();

                    for(i=1;i<N;i++) // For each layer of the film
                    {
                            for(j=0;j<layers[i][2];j++) // For each unit cell
                            {
                                    for (m = 0; m < 1001; m++) // For each row of the diffraction pattern
                                    {
                                            for (n = 0; n <1001; n++) // For each column of the diffraction pattern
                                            {
                                            Rplus1[m][n] = -I*g[i][m][n] + ((1-I*g_0[i][m][n])*(1-I*g_0[i][m][n]))/(I*g[i][m][n] + (cos(-2*phi[i][m][n])+I*sin(-2*phi[i][m][n]))/Rplus1[m][n]);
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }

double stop2 = omp_get_wtime();


double elapsed1 = (double)(stop1 - start1);// Second user defined function to use Durbin and Follis recursive formula
double elapsed2 = (double)(stop2 - start1);// Second user defined function to use Durbin and Follis recursive formula
printf("main() through before diffraction function took %f seconds to run\n\n",elapsed1);
printf("main() through after diffraction function took %f seconds to run\n\n",elapsed2);


}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to ask a more specific question than 'please help'.

Comment: if you change malloc to calloc you can get rid of two for loops that are setting array to zeros. I am not sure how much speed this will get you. Are you compiling with -O3 switch ?

Comment: Hello wdudzik, I thought calloc set the array to zeros and malloc just allocates the memory?  So isn't it the opposite way around?